# How to identify actual service running on a port on a remote server via the terminal?

Tags: ports

I used nmap on my target server which returns the following services

```
PORT     STATE SERVICE       VERSION
53/tcp   open  domain?
80/tcp   open  http          Microsoft IIS httpd 10.0
88/tcp   open  kerberos-sec  Microsoft Windows Kerberos (server time: 2021-03-17 07:07:34Z)
135/tcp  open  msrpc         Microsoft Windows RPC
139/tcp  open  netbios-ssn   Microsoft Windows netbios-ssn
389/tcp  open  ldap
443/tcp  open  https?
445/tcp  open  microsoft-ds?
464/tcp  open  kpasswd5?
593/tcp  open  ncacn_http    Microsoft Windows RPC over HTTP 1.0
636/tcp  open  tcpwrapped
3268/tcp open  ldap
3269/tcp open  tcpwrapped
3389/tcp open  ms-wbt-server Microsoft Terminal Services
```

The question is how to identify the true service running on a port that Nmap might have mistakenly identified. For instance, on port 53, how can I make sure via a terminal that a DNS service is running on it?

Which technique can I use? I don't have access to the target server so I cannot see processes running on the server.

Comment: To make sure that the service is actually  speaking a specific protocol you need to speak to the relevant service according to the protocol and see if you get the expected protocol conform answer back.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Can you please give some commands that I can use to test the services above from terminal? I'm not really sure how to test DNS, LDAP, microsoft-ds,  kpasswd5 from terminal.

Comment: Have you looked at commandline clients for those services? They would be an easy way to confirm. Also, have you tried the extra verbose mode of nmap to see *why* it reports those services on those ports?

Comment: @schroeder I'm a newbie, can you please suggest which command for nmap?

Comment: It's in the documentation: "verbose". https://nmap.org/book/nping-man-output-options.html

Comment: @mentallurg It belongs to pen-testing because we need to verify if service is the one is reported by nmap

Comment: @rubic: Look at the [rules](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Out of scope are questions about "Using or configuring software/hardware".
Even if the tools are used for penetration testing, or for network security, or for application hardening, such questions are still out of scope.
The difference may look subtle in your case. But your question is not about any concepts or approaches. It is just about usage or configuration. Thus it is out of scope on this site.

Comment: If this question were about pen testing, then hammers are a valid topic here, since hammers can be (and are, though not non-destructively) used to penetrate security.

Comment: @Ghedipunk I like your example. Next time, I will bring a hammer to pen-testing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Steffen points out, the way you tell if server X is running at port Y on host Z is you run a client that speaks the same protocol as X, and point it at port Y on host Z. For example, to test whether a given server speaks DNS, you might use any of the many DNS clients, such as `nslookup`.

Of course, this doesn't tell you anything about what's actually running there, aside from that it is compatible with the protocol you used. The server can be almost anything at all. For example, the listener on port 80 (from your example) could just be a tiny script that simply responds to any TCP handshakes with `HTTP 201 No content\r\nServer: Microsoft IIS httpd 10.0\r\n\r\n", which is approximately a valid HTTP response (though it might send that even if the client didn't send an HTTP request) but doesn't mean the listener is in any useful sense a web server, much less that it's specifically IIS 10.0.

Nmap's built-in recognizer scripts are probably better at recognizing most servers than you are, though they're also very inflexible and can be easily fooled if somebody is trying. A human who is familiar with the tools and protocols in question can quite possibly extract more information than the scripts can in unusual cases (such as one server impersonating another, or where an admin has deliberately hidden the usual "tells" that identify a server according to Nmap). However, imparting even the basics of that kind of familiarity in general is beyond the scope of this answer, or indeed this site.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm a newbie, so do you know which tools or documents can be used to test these protocols kpasswd5, ldap, dns, and the common hosting services on Windows. Thanks

Comment: Recommending tools is explicitly out of scope for this site - the recommendations are too opinion-based, and become obsolete too quickly - but in general you can just search "<protocol> client" or "<protocol> tool" or similar. As an example, for [LDAP](https://lmgtfy.app/?q=ldap+client). Note also that anything Nmap identifies with a ? after is a low-confidence guess, probably based on the port alone (e.g. 464 is used for `kpasswd` by default).